After RAVENDB upgrade, the server can't see my databases
I just upgraded my Raven DB from 6.0.1 to 6.0.105.
I did so by downloading the 105 server, unpacked and copied it over my previous instance.
I was able to create a new database, but the server can't see my old databases.
I tried to find this condition on various sites and I looked in the raven help docs. I can't find any solutions or even anyone else with the same problem.
The new database is highlighted in the image. I can see and manipulate that database but none of my old databases show up.
After the upgrade my old cert didn't work. So, I created a new one. Is this issue? If so, how to get the new and old databases to show up together?


So, the answer is painfully simple.
Just create a new database with using the existing data names in the server directory. Jeepers.
